# JNDI Datasource with oracle 12c database issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, oracle12c

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/??"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="20"
          maxIdle="5"
          maxWait="10000"
          username="customer_information_management_db"
          password="123"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"
          />
</Context>
```

what am I doing wrong here? the question mark is there cause I am not understanding what I am supposed to give there. In case of MySQL, I used to give root, what shall I give incase of oracle 12c? sys? I am using ojdbc6 as a connector. Shall I use c##customer_information_management_db for the value of username?